# how to implement observable int in wpf ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my mvvm ViewModel I have such field

```
public int Delta { get; private set; }
```

However when I update it like that:

```
Delta = newValue;
```

UI is not refreshed.

I was thinking that databinding will do that for me. For example I can declare collection as `ObservableCollection` and then databinding will work.

However there are no `ObservableInt`, how to say View that it need to be refreshed then?

Probably I should raise some event "notify property changed" or something?

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track. You need to raise a property changed event. google INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: but how View will know that when certain property is raised certain control need to be udpated?

Comment: The View will know it through the bindings you have.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. Implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface on your class.
2. Inherit from DependencyObject and implement Delta as a DependencyProperty.

The simplest option is #1. You can implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on your class quite easily:

```
public class YourClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

  private int _delta;
  public int Delta
  {
      get { return _delta; }
      set { _delta = value; PropertyChanged?.Invoke(nameof(Delta)); }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

You can read more about [using and implementing dependency properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: +1 Absolutely correct, but for anyone new to WPF, I encourage you to check out the other answers as well, as adopting an existing toolkit will require less work and make learning the framework much easier.

Comment: can I omit `private int _delta;` creation somehow? I want this to be auto-generated by C#, like normal property

Comment: @javapowered: Unfortunately, no. You can't have a "partially implemented" auto-property. And if you need to invoke methods in the setter (as in this case), you have to provide both the backing field and property implementation.

Comment: do you have to use  NotifyPropertyChanged("Delta"); if you want to bind it only one time but not observe changes?

Answer (score 7):

While we're at it with improving the answer, some of the other new additions of c# 6.0 and 7.0 help make it ever more compact:

```
public class Prop<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private T _value;

    public T Value
    {
        get => _value; 
        set { _value = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Value)); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    internal void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => 
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

This way, you aren't using any "embedded values" (i.e - the property's name) and are keeping the code refactor-safe.

And there's also no need for redundant code blocks due to c# 6.0 and 7.0's new Expression body features

Comment: Shouldn't this be ```nameof(value)``` instead of ```nameof(_value)```?  And the parameter could be avoided altogether by using the ```CallerMemberName``` attribute on the ```NotifyPropertyChanged()``` method declaration.

Answer (score 6):

Using @LBushKin's Answer, i modified it to

```
public class Prop<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private T _value;
    public T Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Value"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    internal void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

and to set it up:

```
class MainWindow ...
    // a bool with initial value of true
    public static Prop<bool> optionBool { get; set; } = new Prop<bool>{ Value = true };

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // connect UI to be able to use the Prop
        DataContext = this;
    }
```

and to use it:

```
<Grid ...
    <CheckBox Content="Da Check" ... IsChecked="{Binding optionBool.Value}"/>
```

There is also a Collection and 2-Properties version here:
[Utils.ObservableProperties.cs](https://github.com/BananaAcid/Selfcontained-C-Sharp-WPF-compatible-utility-classes/blob/master/Utils.ObservableProperties.cs) (this repo contains several related classes)

Answer (score 3):

Just implement INotifyPropertyChanged Interface in your class and use it to raise a PropertyChanged for your Property and then UI will update. If you are using an MVVM project template then there is a good chance you already have a helper method implemented you only need to use it.

[MSDN INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)

[GalaSoft MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm)

Answer (score 2):

The `ObservableCollection` raises events automatically but for your own properties you have to raise the events yourself.

A good example is here: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/228352/Naming-Properties-in-MVVM?display=Print

I'd suggest using mvvm light: [http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/), I used it in silverlight and wpf applications. Very easy to use and provides a messageing system between model, view model and view.

Comment: Just a reminder, that even on an ObservableCollection you need to raise property changed in case the reference to the collection itself changes.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8316100/5725669, there is a new and easy way to do this without remembering to keep track of PropertyChanged?.Invoke(nameof(Delta)); in every location

```
public class YourClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private int _delta;
   public int Delta
   {
      get { return _delta; }
      set { 
            _delta = value;               
            // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
            OnPropertyChanged();
          }
   }
   // Declare the event
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

   public YourClass()
   {
   }

   // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
   // The calling member's name will be used as the parameter.
   protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
   {
       PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
   }
}
```

It makes use of [CallerMemberName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/caller-information) for skipping manual entries for property name. More details on this [MSDN Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)